# Agoraphobic returned astronaut rescues his cat on a building ledge

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone identify a pre-1951 story about an agoraphobic returned spacecrewman who must force himself to rescue his cat on a window ledge. It was made into a TV show in the early 1950s- I thought in the brief series "Out There" (CBS, 1951-52), but it doesn't seem to fit any of the listed plots for that series.

Comment: Haven't read the story recently, but I'm pretty sure he was afraid of open spaces.

Comment: @user14111 Stop making changes to the meaning of the question.  Let HenrySirotin clarify his meaning first.

Answer (score 20):

["Ordeal in Space"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58514) by [Robert A. Heinlein](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?29), part of his [*Future History*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?24708) series. The story has its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordeal_in_Space). It was dramatized as Episode 1.2 of the CBS anthology series [*Out There*](http://ctva.biz/US/Anthology/OutThere.htm), airing on Nov. 4, 1951. It was reprinted in [*Nebula Science Fiction*, Number 9, 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59575+c) available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Nebula_09_1954-08).

It wasn't **his** cat, it was a stray kitten:

> He shook his head, then listened. It was real all right. Now he had it identified—a cat, a kitten by the sound of it.
>
> He sat up. Even if he had not had the spaceman's traditional fondness for cats, he would have investigated. However, he liked cats for themselves, quite aside from their neat shipboard habits, and their usefulness in keeping the ship free of those other creatures that go wherever man goes. So he got up at once and looked for this one.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> However, the mewing was louder than ever. It seemed to come from directly under him. Slowly he forced his head out, still clinging to the sill, and made himself look down. Under him, about four feet lower than the edge of the window, a narrow ledge ran around the side of the building. Seated on it was a woebegone ratty-looking kitten. It stared up at him and meowed again.
>
> It was barely possible that, by clinging to the sill with one hand and making a long arm with the other, he could reach it without actually going out the window, he thought—if he could bring himself to do it. He considered calling Tully, then thought better of it. Tully was shorter than he was, had less reach. And the kitten had to be rescued now, before the fluff-brained idiot jumped or fell.

The story alternates between the rescue of the kitten and flashbacks to the "ordeal in space", a mishap which brought on the man's **acrophobia [*]** and forced him to retire from spacing. He has to go outside the spaceship and replace an antenna, while the ship is under spin:

> The rocket ship *Valkyrie* was two hundred and forty-nine days out from Earth-Luna Space Terminal and approaching Mars Terminal on Deimos, outer Martian satellite. William Cole, Chief Communications Officer and relief pilot, was sleeping sweetly when his assistant shook him. "Hey! Bill! Wake up—we're in a jam."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> He could no longer feel his right hand at all.
>
> He could see it slip. It was slipping—
>
> The sudden release in tension let him know that he was falling . . . falling. The ship dropped away from him.
>
> He came to with the captain bending over him. "Just keep quiet, Bill."
>
> "Where—"
>
> "Take it easy. The patrol from Deimos was already close by when you let go. They tracked you on the 'scope, matched orbits with you, and picked you up. First time in history, I guess. Now keep quiet. You're a sick man—you hung there for more than two hours, Bill."
>
> The meowing started up again, louder than ever. He got up on his knees and looked over the windowsill. The kitten was still away to the left on the ledge. He thrust his head cautiously out a little further, remembering not to look at anything but the kitten. "Here, kitty!" he called. "Here, kit-kit-kitty! Here, kitty, come kitty!"

**[*]** The question refers to the man as **agoraphobic** but his condition is more properly described as **acrophobia**: fear of heights, fear of falling. This is explicit in the story:

> The medicos had been very kind, he supposed. "You're lucky. You want to remember that, old fellow. You're still young and your retired pay relieves you of all worry about your future. You've got both arms and legs and are in fine shape."
>
> "Fine shape!" His voice was unintentionally contemptuous.
>
> "No, I mean it," the chief psychiatrist had persisted gently. "The little quirk you have does you no harm at all—except that you can't go out into space again. I can't honestly call **acrophobia** a neurosis; fear of falling is normal and sane. You've just got it a little more strongly than most—but that is not abnormal, in view of what you have been through."
>
> The reminder set him to shaking again. He closed his eyes and saw the stars wheeling below him again. He was falling . . . falling endlessly. The psychiatrist's voice came through to him and pulled him back. "Steady, old man! Look around you."

Comment: Very late getting back to this, but thanks for the answer. That nails it,

Comment: @HenrySirotin You're welcome. If you wish to do so, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: @HenrySirotin By the way, did you mean [agoraphobic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoraphobia) or [acrophobic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia)?